# Upload ZIP file into Jenkins and Extract the ZIP file using Powershell command in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I'm trying to create a job in Jenkins where it will allow the user to upload a zip file then extract to a location.

So far I am able to create the job to upload the zip file, but I'm not able to come up with the PowerShell commands to extract the zip file. Not sure how do I point the file

```
Expand-Archive ??? -DestinationPath C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Folder-B
```

After the job is executed I should be able to see the file extracted to the desired folder.

Comment: there is a path and a literalpath-parameter for that command. see the examples for reference -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-6#examples

Answer (score 0):

As D.J. commented, just use the `-Path` parameter:

```
Expand-Archive -Path "C:\Temp\test.zip" -DestinationPath "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Folder-B"
```